# How to signal to a shell process during script execution?

Tags: shell, batch-file, stdout

Most console application tutorials that I have seen all have this notion of writing to a console. For example:

```
C# => Console.WriteLine(...)
node.js => console.log(...)
ruby/python => print ...
etc. etc.
```

I understand that writing to a console basically means writing to the stdout stream, and that the execution environment (i.e. node.js or CLR for C#) knows what to do with that standard out => Writes to a terminal screen this this case.

Using a terminal based scripting language (I actually need to do this in a `.bat` script, but I'm also interested in knowing how using a `.sh` script), how can I save stdout from a child process into a variable? So something along the lines of this:

```
script1Output=(first instance of stdout from script1)
script2output=(first instance of stdout from script2)
etc
```

Script 1 and Script 2 are long running console apps. I need to wait for some data to be cached in script 1 before launching script 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cmd interpreter uses `for /F` to capture and parse the output of a command.  See `for /?` in a cmd console for full details.  Basically, you'd do something like this:

```sh
@echo off & setlocal

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`cmd /c "child1.bat"`) do (
    echo(%%~I
    set "output=%%~I"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    rem # If !output! contains "Test String"...
    if not "!output!"=="!output:Test String=!" (

        rem # Do this to spawn child2.bat asynchronously
        start /b "" "child2.bat"

        rem # Or if you prefer child2.bat to block...
        rem # call "child2.bat"
    )
    endlocal
)
```

In a .sh script (presumably with `#!/bin/bash` at the top) you can capture output to a variable much more easily.

```sh
output=$(command)
echo $output
```

But I'm guessing that's not what quite you want, since `echo $output` never fires until `command` has terminated, right?  In that case, maybe you could leverage `awk` to monitor the output of `command` and spawn a process when the appropriate output is detected?

```sh
# limit charset to optimize execution efficiency
export LC_ALL=C

bash -c ./child1.sh | awk '1;/Test String/ { system("(bash -c ./child2.sh) &") }'
```

Or slightly more complicated, you can process in pure bash without depending on awk:

```sh
export LC_ALL=C

bash -c ./child1.sh | while IFS='' read -r line; do {
    echo $line
    [[ $line =~ "Test String" ]] && ./child2.sh &
}; done
```